# Do [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)] have a counter part in fluent api?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, fluent

If not mistaken, the counter part of DataAnnotation of `[DataType(DataType.Currency)]` in Fluent api is `modelBuilder.Entity<T>.Property(i => i.Price).HasColumnType("Currency")`.

Then what is the counter part of `[DataType(DataType.EmaillAddress)]`?

Or is there a site that has a list of if-you-can-do-in-data-annotation-you-can-do-it-in-fluent-api. Because I want to do the validation and mapping using Fluent Api. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a notoriously confusing area.

About your examples:

- A property that is annotated by `[DataType(DataType.Currency)]` is implemented as `decimal(18,2)` (in Sql Server). **Close**.
- The fluent mapping `HasColumnType("Money")` (not "Currency") creates the column as `Money` data type. A **perfect** match.
- A string property annotated by `[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]` will be created as `nvarchar(max)`. Granted, that's enough for an email address. But it's **nowhere near** a data type that enforces a specific format.

Surely EF could do better than that, could it? Well, in the latter case, what should it do? There is no built-in email datatype and I think we can't expect EF to create a user-defined type on the fly with rules and all (not to mention that rules in Sql Server are deprecated).

The confusing part is that data annotations are used differently by different frameworks as is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5356222/861716).

I'm not sure whether the EF team made the right decision by implementing a *subset* of the annotations in code-first. Of course they can't implement *all* attributes in the extensive System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations namespace. But the current implementation is half-hearted at best. The examples above are only a small demonstration - one annotation is implemented, another isn't. And, for that matter, EF happily allows you to annotate an `int` property as `EmailAddress`.

Therefore, to answer your question, there is no fluent counterpart of `DataType.EmailAddress`. There is nothing to counterpart.

On the other hand, to speak up for EF, not implementing the annotations at all would have forced us to do many things redundantly. If we use MVC and EF together the annotations can be applied once and both systems concur pretty well. It would have been a tedious job to make the annotations and the fluent configurations match.

Unfortunately, I can't find any source disclosing the full mapping between annotations and fluent API. Maybe that's the worst part: we have to find out by trial and error. Anybody out there to enlighten us?

Answer (score 0):

I think your first example is a coincidence, the `DataType` annotation is for specifying a more appropriate CLR type.  Nothing to do with databases at all, as it could also be used when serializing

The `HasColumnType` obviously is for databases and I thought it was for when EF made an incorrect choice, space saving issues, or you added your own custom types to the database.

In my own work I've gone with the rule that I can use annotations as long as they're in `ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` namespace, anything else (that is likely EF specific) is being done via Fluent, as these are the bits more likely to change if a different ORM is used.