# Remove required attribute - EF Code first

Tags: entity-framework, model, attributes, data-annotations

I've got an abstract class where a property "CreatedBy" is required.
This is used for ALMOST every entities but one (UserProfile itself)

How can I remove the Required attribute from the UserProfile without removing it from the other entities inheriting from EntityBase?

```
public abstract class EntityBase: IEntityBase
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public Guid? Id { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int Version { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public UserProfile CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}

public class UserProfile: EntityBase
{
    [Required, Index("Username", 3, IsUnique = true), MaxLength(900)]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required, Index("Email", 4, IsUnique = true), MaxLength(900)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

I tried overriding my OnModelCreating, but that doesn't work... Anybody any ideas?

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserProfile>().HasOptional(profile => profile.CreatedBy).WithMany();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
    }
```

Strange thing is, in my database, the columns CreatedBy_Id and CreatedBy_Version can be null in the UserProfile table.

When I seed my UserProfile table, I get a validation error for each of them saying: "The CreatedBy field is required."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're actually designing wrong.

Your requirement clearly means you shouldn't inherit from the EntityBase. You shouldn't be trying to force this design onto your requirement.

Instead relax your EntityBase.

```
public abstract class EntityBase: IEntityBase
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public Guid? Id { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int Version { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    public UserProfile CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

Problem solved.

This is the correct way to do this. Entities can come from anywhere, they are not always created by a user at all, so it is quite wrong to put a requirement in your design which says "all entities must be made by a user".

Comment: what about if I have not access to the `EntityBase` code? I mean: how to solve the issue if `EntityBase` comes from a library? Is there a way to remove the unwanted attribute?

Comment: If you are using EntityFramework, you might be able to "overwrite" the attribute by using the FluentAPI instead. I had to do exactly this to with some attributes I had from another library, which we're compatible with an oracle database. FluentAPI takes priority.
FYI, just inherit the EntityBase and re-write the same properties with new/override, and that should wipe the attributes.

Answer (score 0):

The funny thing here is that the database generation logic is overridden by the fluent mapping, but the validation logic isn't. It's [not the only area](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24336709/861716) where there is tension between fluent mapping and data annotations.

The first thing that springs to my mind is: make one exception for the `UserProfile` class and don't let it inherit from `EntityBase`, and give it the properties it needs, among which the properties also found in `EntityBase`.

But I bet you have code elsewhere that relies on your classes inheriting the base class or implementing the interface.

The problem here is that `RequiredAttribute` has `Inherited = true` in its specification (from its base class, `Attribute`), so if you override `CreatedBy` in `UserProfile` it's still required.

#### Solution 1 - not good

To solve this problem you could create your own attribute, inheriting `RequiredAttribute`, and make it `Inherited = false`:

```
[AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Parameter, 
    AllowMultiple = false,
    Inherited = false)]
public class RequiredInBaseClassAttribute : RequiredAttribute
{
}
```

Now if you put this attribute in the base class...

```
[RequiredInBaseClass]
public virtual UserProfile CreatedBy { get; set; }
```

and override it in UserProfile...

```
public override UserProfile CreatedBy { get; set; }
```

it's not required any more in `UserProfile`. Well, it is. EF seems to trace back the attribute on the base property.

#### Solution 2

Replace the `Required` attribute by a `CustomValidation` attribute that allows `CreatedBy` to be null when the validated type is a `UserProfile`:

```
public abstract class EntityBase: IEntityBase
{
    ...
    
    [CustomValidation(typeof(EntityBase), "CreatedByIsValid")]
    public UserProfile CreatedBy { get; set; }
    
    public static ValidationResult CreatedByIsValid(UserProfile value, ValidationContext context)
    {
        return value != null || (context.ObjectInstance is UserProfile) 
            ? ValidationResult.Success 
            : new ValidationResult("CreatedBy is required");
    }
}
```

Comment: Very well explained and great solution! I'll test this right away.

Comment: Tried it, but I still have the same problem. Any other solutions you know of?

Comment: The only way I know of... is to remove the required attribute from my EntityBase and add a 'HasRequired' in the OnModelCreating for every other class deriving from EntityBase. But if there should be an easier, better solution, I'll change it. So suggestions are still welcome

Comment: It seems that EF traces back the attribute on the base property. Even putting a `CustomValidationAttribute` (always returning Success) on the override doesn't remove the required validation.