# EF Core API how to remove the Required value

Tags: c#, api, swagger, swagger-ui, ef-core-5.0

How to remove the Required value of Remarks property I'm not setting the value as required, when I run the swagger the Remarks parameter set as required here is my Entities

```
public class FixedAsset
{
    public long FixedAssetMovementEntitiesId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string FixedAssetId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string FixedAssetDescription { get; set; }        
    public int ServiceLife { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Company { get; set; }        
    public string Remarks { get; set; }        
    public IsReturnedEnum IsReturned { get; set; }
}
```

My Base DataContracts inherited from Interface

```
public class BaseFixedAssetMovement : InterfaceFixedAssetMovement
{
    [Required]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string FixedAssetId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string FixedAssetDescription { get; set; }        
    public int ServiceLife { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Company { get; set; }        
    public string Remarks { get; set; }        
    public IsReturnedEnum IsReturned { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Have you enabled nullable reference types?

Comment: not yet i'm new to this I will make a research of it thank you for the help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove required attribute - EF Code first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27178163/remove-required-attribute-ef-code-first)