# Mixing data annotations with fluent API throws EntityType has no key defined for every class in context

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, data-annotations, ef-fluent-api

So i have an existing class, which looks like this:

```
Public Class Song

    <Key>
    Public Property GUID As Guid

    <ForeignKey("Creator")>
    Public Property GUID_Creator As Guid

    Public Property Creator As User

End Class
```

This works perfectly, i'm able to add new songs and all that.

Recently, i decided i need to map some things using the Fluent API, but i didn't want to remake my whole model using the API, all i needed was just disabling cascade delete.
So i wandered off to `onModelCreating`, to add

```
modelBuilder.Entity(Of Song) _

    .HasRequired(Function(s) s.Creator) _
    .WithMany(Function(u) u.Songs) _
    .HasForeignKey(Function(s) s.GUID_Creator) _
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(False)
```

I have added just that, the method was empty before. When firing the app after this (i have auto migrations enabled) and using the context, suddenly i get an exception for EVERY SINGLE CLASS in my context, saying:

```
EntityType 'Song' has no key defined
EntityType 'User' has no key defined
```

etc. I Googled for people using both Fluent API and Data Annotations at the same time, and found some people that had it working. Adding `HasKey` in the Fluent API solves it, but i don't wanna remake every class in `OnModelCreating`.

So how do i go about it? Is it possible to mix Fluent API and Data Annotations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i found my mistake, and i feel really stupid :D

What i have in my project is two classes:

```
Public Class Song 'Class for use in my apps and services
Public Class EF_Song 'Class for use with Entity Framework
```

So the entire problem was me using the class `Song` instead of `EF_Song`.
The exception thrown was about all "standard" classes, because it tried to load them into the model based on their relationship with the `Song` class (obviously, the classes not meant for use with Entity Framework didn't have keys defined).

Answer (score 0):

Have a try and remove the line `.HasKey(Function(s) s.GUID) _` from your entity calls, because you already defined it via *Data Annotations* and you only want to set up the *relation*:

```
modelBuilder.Entity(Of Song) _
    .HasRequired(Function(s) s.Creator) _
    .WithMany(Function(u) u.Songs) _
    .HasForeignKey(Function(s) s.GUID_Creator) _
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(False)
```

It should work that way. Maybe this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29668136/entity-framework-code-first-attributes-in-combination-with-fluent-api-configurat) will help you.

But I have to recommend that you should avoid mixing Data Annotations and FluentAPI, because of splitting entity-definitions into different files will be much more error-prone!

Comment: I have edited the question, the `HasKey()` isn't in my code when this happens.

Comment: Okay. Could you add your condext class and relation related entity classes to the question. Currently I cannot see why it should not work.

Comment: My context class doesn't have anything else in it - just standard DbSets and a config that only enables auto migrations. I'll add for now that clean+rebuild didn't fix this. Also, I would have to upload my entire model, which I prefer not to do - the exception mentions every single class having no key (it worked before, and it works if I clean the `onModelCreating` function)

Comment: I see. Have you tried to remove the cascade on delete conventions?

`protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
}`
That will remove the cascade delete on all tables in your context, don't know if it is acceptable.

Comment: No, unfortunately I need cascade delete in most of my database. Might be a good last resort solution though.