# How to Inherit from IdentityUserLogin And IdentityUserRole asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I have a two classes they are names tblUserProfile and tblUserRole I want to add multiple property to my own class that i mentioned.in fact , tblUserProfile use `tblUserProfile:IdentityUserLogin` and tblUserRole use `tblAccessRole : IdentityUserRole` but when I did add-migration it did give me this error `EntityType  has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType`
after that I add key attribute then EF did show me `Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'RoleId' in table 'tblAccessRoles' is specified more than once.` please tell me how can i solve it.

```
   public class tblUserProfile : IdentityUserLogin
    {
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string NameFamily { get; set; }

    }

  public class tblAccessRole : IdentityUserRole
    {

        public int RoleID { get; set; }
        public string  Section { get; set; }
        public bool IsSave { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `UserID` from `tblUserProfile` and `RoleID` from `tblAccessRole` and

In Your DbContext add :

```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

      modelBuilder.Entity<tblUserProfile>()//IdentityUserLogin
            .HasKey(l => new { l.LoginProvider, l.ProviderKey, l.UserId })
            .ToTable("tblUserProfile");// Database Table Nam    

            modelBuilder.Entity<tblAccessRole>()//IdentityUserRole
            .HasKey(r => new { r.UserId, r.RoleId })
                .ToTable("tblAccessRole");// Database Table Name
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.my problem is solved .but I have a question, why should I use Fluent API approach?

Comment: @behnam please read the answer of  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5354900/code-first-are-data-annotations-or-the-fluent-api-better