# Entity Framework Core Fluent API/Annotations

Tags: design-patterns, .net-core, annotations, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

## Which is better to use?

I don't have much experience with EF or EF Core patterns. When I'm reading articles about Entity Framework some peoples are using annotations for annotating PKs, FKs, Generated values, etc. and other people (I think more common case) are using Fluent API for same purpose.

What I'm interested in is that if there is any significant difference between this two approaches.

**Main questions are:**

- Can I do more with Fluent API or vice versa?
- Is it just question of preference or it depends on project type or size?
- Is it good idea to combine those two approaches in some way?
- Should I avoid using annotations?

I know there is no just one answer for those questions but I wonder what is opinion of experienced developers.

Currently i intend to use this pattern for entity configuration: [source](https://medium.com/@marekzyla95/entityframeworkmapping-c2e3f9bbe831)

Please, feel free to correct my question grammatically.

### Update

I apologize that I overlooked the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5354900/entity-framework-code-first-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-fluent-api-vs-data) mentioned in comment. It answered most of the questions but one question stays.

- Is it bad idea to combine annotations with fluent API and I should only use one approach? Let say I'm using Fluent API and I want just define one property in entity as optional and I don't want to create Fluent API for that simple case. Is it all right to use annotation just in that one case and Fluent API for the rest?

Comment: Check this question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5354900/7877686)

Comment: Thanks @Fidan. It answered the most of the questions but one remains. I already updated my question.

Comment: i think it's ok to combine for such case, at least at first sight there is no any problems with that

Comment: I’m just thinking that with Fluent API, the DbContext class could get pretty huge and hardly readable. With entity configurations, there could be many files just for setting little things as optional parameters so annotations would be better in that case. The think I’m thinking about is if it wouldn’t be confusing later if the project gets bigger.

Comment: I prefer to follow SRP especially for large projects. That is, go for `IEntityTypeConfiguration`.

Comment: @Fidan That article is 8 years old and about EF, not EF Core, do we know if its answer still holds true?